# Downloading a file from the internet with '&' in URL using wget

Tags: pdf, download, wget

I'm trying to download a file from a URL that looks like this:

```
http://pdf.example.com/filehandle.ashx?p1=ABC&p2=DEF.pdf
```

Within the browser, this link prompts me to download a file called x.pdf irrespective of what DEF is (but 'x.pdf' is the right content).

However using wget, I get the following:

```
>wget.exe http://pdf.example.com/filehandle.ashx?p1=ABC&p2=DEF.pdf
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2011-01-06 07:52:05--  http://pdf.example.com/filehandle.ashx?p1=ABC
Resolving pdf.example.com... 99.99.99.99
Connecting to pdf.example.com|99.99.99.99|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2011-01-06 07:52:08 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.

'p2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This is on a Windows Vista system

---

Edit1

```
>wget.exe "http://pdf.example.com/filehandle.ashx?p1=ABC&p2=DEF.pdf"
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2011-02-06 10:18:31--  http://pdf.example.com/filehandle.ashx?p1=ABC&p2=DEF.pdf
Resolving pdf.example.com... 99.99.99.99
Connecting to pdf.example.com|99.99.99.99|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4568 (4.5K) [image/JPEG]
Saving to: `filehandle.ashx@p1=ABC&p2=DEF.pdf'

100%[======================================>] 4,568       --.-K/s   in 0.1s

2011-02-06 10:18:33 (30.0 KB/s) - `filehandle.ashx@p1=ABC&p2=DEF.pdf'
 saved [4568/4568]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the address in quotes, i.e.:

`wget.exe "http://pdf.example.com/filehandle.ashx?p1=ABC&p2=DEF.pdf"`

Comment: Hi @ultrasawblade - please see Edit1 - it didnt download the file properly

Comment: @matt_tm: You will need to use `-O` and specify the output filename.

Comment: @Dennis - it looks like the wrong option - "  -o,  --output-file=FILE    log messages to FILE.". I tried it of course and got the log messages redirected there...

Comment: @Dennis - its weird, I tried -O (capital "oh") and it didnt work exactly. It downloaded some 5k bytes into an invalid PDF which when I opened it in notepad, showed up as chinese characters on my system.

Comment: What does the `file` utility say when you run it on that file? If you load that URL in a browser, do you get a valid PDF?

Comment: Hi @Dennis - within a browser, if I try opening up the URL, it prompts me to download a file called 'x.pdf' as a _separate_ file (which does have the right content). About the file, it actually is a gif file which is a logo of the system used by the example.com server

Comment: Oh okay - I figured it out... I need to be "logged in" for it to give me the 'x.pdf' file, otherwise it displays the logo on the main site... not sure how to get wget to do that